# SyntaxError: bad input ('def')

Tags: python

I am doing Coursera mini project.

I got this problem as bad input ('def') for the line def range100(). I am trying to play guess number game in the range. I check the indentation and it's all right. Please help. Thanks

```
import simplegui
import random
import math

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    # initialize global variables used in your code here
    global secret_number
    low = 0
    global n
    if range100():
        high = math.ceil(100)
        n = int(math.log((high - low + 1),2))
    elif range1000():
        high = math.ceil(1000)
        n = int(math.log((high - low + 1),2)



# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global secret_number
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 100)
    return True


def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1000)
    return True


def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here 
    global secret_number
    guess_num = int(guess)
    print 'Guess was %s' %guess_num
    global n
    if secret_number > guess_num:
        print 'Lower'
        n -= 1
        if n >= 0:
            print 'Number of remaining guesses is %s' %n
        else:
            print 'You are running out of chances'
            new_game()
    elif secret_number < guess_num:
        print 'Higher'
        n -= 1
        if n >= 0:
            print 'Number of remaining guesses is %s' %n
        else:
            print 'You are running out of chances'
            new_game()
    else:
        print 'Correct'



# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame('Guess the number',200, 200)
frame.add_input('Input Guess:', input_guess, 100)
frame.add_button('Range is [0, 100)', range100, 100)
frame.add_button('Range is [0, 1000)', range1000, 100)

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame.start()

# call new_game 
new_game()
```

I am trying to count guess and output the outcome. But I can't pass this run as I  don't know why def is a syntax wrong....

Comment: Missing a `)` on the previous line.

Comment: In the future, please provide the full traceback of your error instead of saying "on the line def range100()". Full tracebacks are more helpful and help identify the issue faster.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you are missing a parenthesis in the line before `def range100()`. The line should be `n = int(math.log((high - low + 1),2))`.